# Can’t install ipopt 3.11.1 solver in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, solver, ipopt

I try to install ipopt 3.11.1  under ubuntu server 20 using this command

`conda install -c conda-forge ipopt`

and it displays this error :

`/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/ipopt-3.13.2-hc6e8484_0/bin/ipopt: error while loading shared libraries: liblapack.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Has anyone had the same problem? And how did you solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the library from conda-forge has a dependency on Lapack, but noone took care of ensuring that Lapack is also present. Try installing it via the Ubuntu package manager or conda.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting some permission errors. You can try creating a new conda environment and try installing ipopt in that environment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).